# queue downloading of a lot of images in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

is there some new framework additions for doing something like this in iOS 4 now?  I kow I could use http://allseeing-i.com/ but that would require a big change of my code and would rather use what is available to me.

EDIT SOLUTION:
Here is the solution I ended up with and it is working like a charm for 3000+ images:

```
int j = 0;
        do{
            NSLog(@"x = %i, items count: %i", j, [items count]);

            if ((int)[[self networkQueue] requestsCount] < 100) {

                NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://images.myurl.com/skus/%@/%@_tn.jpg",[[[manufacturers objectAtIndex:i] ManufacturerID] stringValue], [[items objectAtIndex:j]  valueForKey:@"PhotoName"]];
                NSString *url2 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://images.myurl.com/skus/%@/%@_lg.jpg",[[[manufacturers objectAtIndex:i] ManufacturerID] stringValue], [[items objectAtIndex:j]  valueForKey:@"PhotoName"]];

                ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];

                ASIHTTPRequest *request2 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url2]];
                [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request2];

                if (j==0) {
                    [[self networkQueue] go];
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(j < [items count]);
```

Just queueing up 100 at a time and as they fall off I add more, looks like my memory consumption starts to creep up a bit as it goes so I am working on that, it goes down after the queue is complete though.

Comment: thanks for the delightfully creative insight, changing careers now.  I didn't realize that apple would have to buy out ASIHttpRequest to create a queueing feature - must be awesome for them to have cornered the market on that.

Comment: You certainly can write your own image download network queue. Maybe make it open source and encourage others to test it for you in thousands of apps, run a support forum to get insight into all of the ways your code can fail, and get lots of good code improvements to fold in. After a year or three you should have something really solid, with great multitasking support, reliable queueing, that's comparatively easy to integrate into any app. I look forward to the possibility of such a thing.

Comment: I was simply asking if there was an efficient queue process built into iOS4 and, see the answer below - no condescension necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I think the mood of the previous comments infected me. Your question is certainly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may take some reworking of your network interface code, but switching to ASI will SO pay off in the long run.

(That's ASIHttpRequest, at http://allseeing-i.com/Tags/ASIHTTPRequest )

Comment: It was totally worth it, blazes through the image download at least 5 times as fast.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the queue that ASI provides is a wrapper around NSOperationQueue, but it's SO much easier to use.

Comment: thanks - it is really simple to use. now the problem I seem to be facing is how may operations you can actually stuff into that queue